# Task doesnt have the approve button

Tags: workflow

Finally I was able to start runing my workflow, it starts ok, and then it generates a task, but when I go to the task, it doesnt have the Approve or Reject buttons, What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workflow task doesn't have Approve/Reject functionality out of the box.  You can only mark it as complete.  If you edit the workflow task you should see a "Complete Task" button.  Click it and the workflow will continue.

Comment: a nd how can I edit that form? MY first example was done with spd and infopath and I did an approve and reject buttons, but this example is with vs 2010

Comment: My apologies, Luis.  I didn't catch that you were using SPD.  See if this one helps: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/design-custom-workflows-by-using-sharepoint-designer-HA010242295.aspx  (Note the custom task wizard)

Comment: I am not using SPD,  this example was built with VS 2010, and the task form only has a save button but there is no Complete task button there.

Comment: I think I'm with you now.  One thing I wanted to mention is that you may be able to use the built-in approval workflow for what you need if you have SharePoint Server 2010.  See http://www.sharepointmonitor.com/2010/01/building-approval-workflows-with-sharepoint-server-2010/ for more information.  
For Visual Studio specific workflows, check out this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/660b154c-1c20-4ccf-948b-53f947799cbf .  They should work in 2010 as well as 2007.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I am just following a tutorial on the wrox book Sharepoint 2010 Professioanl Development and the first tutorail I did was on SPD 2010 and it had an approve button, but this second tutorial its the same workflow but with visual studio, and after reading detailed again I didnt saw a way to customize the task form, or to put an approve button there like I did with SPD 2010 and Infopath

Comment: Gotcha.  What do you think of the book?  You recommend it?

Comment: Its perfect, I just realized, I was takin a deep look to the ontaskchanged, and it approves the task when the description contains the word Approved, lol, but I still have the question, Isnt it possible to customize the Task form for VS 2010 Workflows?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, "%complete" and "task status" fields are not hidden in content type. They are necessary for task outcome works correctly.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/16635209-28f8-481b-a909-a5bb79576333/task-outcome-buttons-disapeared?prof=required